# VBA loop freezes/crashes word after first iteration

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to determine the total width of each table in a word document. After the first iteration, the script hangs and Microsoft Word stops responding.

```
Sub fixTableAlignment()
    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
      Dim tRng As Range
      Dim sngWdth As Single
      Set tRng = tTable.Cell(1, 1).Range
      sngWdth = -tRng.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
      Do While tRng.Cells(1).RowIndex = 1
        tRng.Move unit:=wdCell, Count:=1
      Loop
      tRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
      sngWdth = sngWdth + tRng.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
      MsgBox PointsToInches(sngWdth)
    Next tTable
  End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried to single step through the code with `F8`?

Comment: Does it help if you move the two `Dim` statements above the `For Each` statement? With my testing it doesn't cause a problem, but there's no reason to keep re-declaring them.

Comment: Sean, I unfortunately need it to work in a single run.
Doug, I have :/  Are you saying that this script works OK for you as is?
Thank you both very much for the replies!

Comment: Sorry, no I wasn't saying that. I did a simple test - not your code - thinking it was the Dim's in a loop, but it worked fine. I think @SeanCheshire's suggestion of debugging one line of code at a time with `F8` is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as presented doesn't work for tables which consist of a single row. This `Do While` loop:

```
Do While tRng.Cells(1).RowIndex = 1
    tRng.Move unit:=wdCell, Count:=1
Loop
```

breaks out once we find a cell which isn't in row 1. If there is only a single row then every cell is in row 1.

The `Move` method returns 0 if the move was unsuccessful so this should work:

```
Dim lngSuccess As Long

For Each ttable In ThisDocument.Tables
  Set tRng = ttable.Cell(1, 1).Range
  sngWdth = -tRng.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)

  ' Any non-zero value will do here
  lngSuccess = 1
  Do While tRng.Cells(1).RowIndex = 1 And lngSuccess <> 0
    lngSuccess = tRng.Move(unit:=wdCell, Count:=1)
  Loop

  tRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
  sngWdth = sngWdth + tRng.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
  MsgBox PointsToInches(sngWdth)
Next tTable
```

Also of note: `tTable` isn't declared in your original code so declare it in the method (and use `Option Explicit` if not already doing so). The part of the code causing the error could have been tracked down by pressing `<Ctrl>-<Break>` when Word stopped responding - this would have led you straight to the `While` loop

---

*edit to deal with incorrect width on single-row tables:*

This new version uses the `Cell.Width` property to measure the width of the table. I couldn't find a reliable way of using `Range.Information` to measure the width of a single-row table

```
Option Explicit

Sub fixTableAlignment()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell
    Dim sngWdth As Single
    Dim bFinished As Boolean

    For Each tTable In ThisDocument.Tables
        Set cCell = tTable.Cell(1, 1)
        sngWdth = 0

        ' Can't just check the row index as cCell
        ' will be Nothing when we run out of cells
        ' in a single-row table. Can't check for
        ' Nothing and also check the row index in
        ' the Do statement as VBA doesn't short-circuit
        bFinished = False
        Do Until bFinished
            sngWdth = sngWdth + cCell.Width
            Set cCell = cCell.Next

            If (cCell Is Nothing) Then
                bFinished = True
            ElseIf (cCell.RowIndex <> 1) Then
                bFinished = True
            End If
        Loop

        MsgBox PointsToInches(sngWdth)
    Next tTable
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you barrowc. I have one last question.. that script throws an error on tables with only 1 row - I am very new to VBA, how can I handle this exception for the Do While statement? "The requested member of the collection does not exist."

Comment: I tested it on a single-row table before posting the answer. It worked OK in Word 2003. I've tested it again just now and it doesn't create an error. It does, however, report the wrong length for single-row tables as it moves back to the second-last cell. I'll edit my answer to correct this

Comment: Actually it moves back to the second-last character but my table has one character per cell